# How do you override a back form button if visitors have just landed on a website

Tags: html, css

I have added a back form button to my website, which works great, but i am wondering if it is possible to replace it with a home button if a visitor has just landed on my website.

This is my form button:

```
<FORM><INPUT VALUE='Back' id='backbutton' onClick='history.go(-1);return true;'    type='button'/></FORM>
```

and i want it to be replaced by this if visitors have just landed on my website:

```
<FORM><INPUT VALUE='Home' id='homebutton' onClick='href="http://www.gamer4eva.com/"' type='button'/></FORM>
```

Comment: judging from your tags, you'd like to achieve this by just using html and css?

Comment: @bitoshi.n ...or another language (like PHP) and sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You could see if the visitor is from your site with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Best use preg_match on it to get the domain, and if its not your site that means they came from somewhere else.

This is not 100% accurate though, since users can edit the HTTP_REFERER value.

Good luck

Comment: There is no mention of javascript either, and with just html and css you cannot do this.

Comment: Then you should just indicate so rather than blindly give solutions in an arbitrary language... IMHO

Comment: Feel free to press the down arrow, I don't get why people rage at awnsers to quickly on this site. We are all here to help and lurn stuff are we not?

Comment: ... I'm not raging at all, why did you think so? Which is why I didn't downvote you as I think your answer is still correct, if the OP does indeed using PHP. Nevermind me then, have a good day..

Answer (score 1):

This is a clientside solution:

```
onClick="(document.referrer.match('gamer4eva.com') || document.referrer === "")?href='http://www.gamer4eva.com/':history.go(-1)"
```

and you don't need a form for that. Better use an anchor:

```
<a href="#" onclick="...">Back</a>
```

of course you could also check this serverside. Depends on your taste.